# What is the simplest way to setup a server to read data from incoming socket connections?

Tags: objective-c, sockets

What is the simplest way (preferably without using third party frameworks) in objective c, to setup a simple server that listens for socket connections, and reads data from the clients on a line by line basis.

ie Ideally you would just need to create an instance of a "server" object, that would pass "client" objects back to which receive incoming data messages.

Comment: Good question, i would love to find an easy way to do this. It seems odd that in this day and age client/server code would have to be developed from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been open for a long time. There appears to be no standard way to do this. I ended up just writing my own Objective C code to wrap C

There are some other "libraries" out there, but I find a couple of .m and .h files much easier to work with than tracking some third party library thats big and complicated and possibly has undiscovered bugs in features I don't want to use anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here [How to Write a Cocoa Web Server](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2006/11/14/how-to-write-a-cocoa-web-server.html)

Maybe not the *simplest* solution but it gives a good insight of needed logic for a *server*

Comment: I was hoping cocoa, or some other framework can take care of most of the work and just pass on actual connections to my code (:

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are classes out there, with which, in a couple of lines of code, you could write a simple socket server.

For eg, search for TcpListener() on Google and see if that works for you. I am sure there are examples for Java as well.

Comment: Thanks feroze, but I am doing objective-c, I did tag as objective-c, maybe I should have put it in the question as well. (The subject line was already getting really long)