# iphone - create http server and connect via hotspot

Tags: ios, iphone, http

I am interested if there is a way to create a HTTP server on iPhone and connect to it via iphone hotspot, so it would no need for any other infrastructure (e.g. lan).

I would like to send it some data and it will need to process that data and show some results on iphone screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Cocoa HTTP Server](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

It's very simple to use. Once the server is started and you know the IP address of your iphone, you can start sending requests.

Comment: Hi, I found this and marked is as the best solution: Bus as I am beginner with this I am not sure how to start it. I used one of examples (iPhoneHTTPServer) but I am not sure how to connect to it. Could you hint me a bit. Thanks, Ante.

Comment: Connect to the network from your iphone. Check your IP address (can be seen in the network settings), e.g. `192.168.0.5` or something similar. Start your application. Now open browser on your desktop and enter `http://<the-ip-address>`

Comment: Hi, I have been trying that before, but my desktop browser could not connect to iphone using it's ip addr. Could there be a problem with ports, can I change port to some other i order to test connection? Thanks

Comment: @AnteBraovic The server has a `setPort:` method. If you don't set it, it will get assigned a random port.

Comment: Would love to know if this actually works. Looks like answer was accepted but not tried. Specifically I would like to run a webserver on iPhone and connect to it via hotspot connected android device. No router involved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can just listen to a port in an iPhone app from the restrictions given (as you are sandboxed and only certain system calls are allowed).

However this might help you

[What is the simplest way to setup a server to read data from incoming socket connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419419/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-setup-a-server-to-read-data-from-incoming-socket-con)